# Cannot cd to directory when running a Gradle build in Docker with Jenkins

Tags: docker, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I want to build a Gradle based project in a Jenkins pipeline. The build step shall run in a Docker container. This is my current pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        GRADLE_DOCKER_IMAGE = 'gradle:5.6.4-jdk8'
        GRADLE_DOCKER_ARGS  = '-v ${HOME}/.m2:/maven/.m2'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Compile') {
            steps {
                script{
                    docker.image(GRADLE_DOCKER_IMAGE).inside("${GRADLE_DOCKER_ARGS}") {
                        sh './gradlew clean build --scan -s'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The pipeline itself finishes successfully but there is the following message in the log:

`./gradlew: 23: cd: can't cd to "./`

If I omit the `./` (using just `sh 'gradlew ...`) then the build fails as the command gradlew cannot be found.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess this is cause by the [following line of code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/gradlew#L39) but it should not output anything. If it does no brake your build, I would not worry about it. Else you can try to pass an abosolute path using the `$WORSPACE` environment variable for example which should fix the message you see in logs.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally allowed your editor to format your `gradlew` file (`./gradlew` always complaints when I let IntelliJ format it). Also, you might want to try `sh -c '<commands>'` (note the `-c`).

Answer (score 0):

Do not format `gradlew` file with Intellij idea

For fix redownload file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradle/gradle/master/gradlew